# Using sched_setscheduler

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, scheduler

How can I use `sched_setscheduler` explained in this [topic](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setscheduler)? It seems that I have to write a C code and run it on shell?

Comment: That's the man page for the system call. So yes, it's showing you how to do that from a C program. Is that what you need?

Comment: Basically I want to know is it possible to change the scheduling policy (fifo,fair,...) on the fly from shell or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the policy of a process from the shell you need to use [chrt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chrt). To choose real time priorities you must be root. Beware that this is dangerous, raising priorities higher than the kernel interrupts will definitely have strange side effects!